# É possível mudar porta de uma conexão HTTPS no CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-aws, https, cdn

Tenho um serviço rodando na porta 8090, ao configurar o CDN no AWS CloudFront é possível trocar a porta http de 80 para 8090, e funciona normalmente, porém ao trocar https 443 para 8090 dá erro:

**ERROR**

**The request could not be satisfied.**

**CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.**

existe alguma forma de executar tal serviço em https e em porta diferente?

obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava em minha própria configuração do CloudFront, minha origem não tem ssl, então a comunicação do CloudFront com a origem deve ser http.

Tinha configurado no CloudFront pra ser **Match Viewer**, nesse caso ele ia fazer a comunicação com a origem da mesma forma que era feita no CloudFront, se http faz http, se https faz https...